# Best Practice to avoid ec2 downtime and redirecting to static page

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are using elastic beanstalk

Environment Details
Environment type: Load balanced, auto scaling
Number instances: 1 - 10
Scale based on Average CPUUtilization
Add instance when > 84
Remove instance when < 20

Instance type: m1.small
Root volume type: General Purpose (SSD)
Availability Zones: Any
Environment variables: PARAM3, PARAM2, PARAM1, PARAM5, PARAM4, AWS_SECRET_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
Log publication: On
Enable 32-bit Applications: False
Target Runtime: 4.0

Application deployment batch size: 100%
Rolling updates are disabled

Application health check URL: /
Load Balancing
Port: HTTP on port 80
Port: 80
Secure port: HTTPS on port 443
Secure port: 443
Health: Requests / over HTTP on port 80
Cross-zone load balancing is disabled
Connection draining is disabled

Availability zone: us-west-2a

We do have another Ec2 - Linux -hosting the database:

Instance type
m1.small
Availability zone
us-west-2a
Background
On 2015-10-12
the windows instance reported unhealthy and not reachable/responding to Amazon Service.
the new instance took time 12-15 minutes for initializing
The status check, network check, amazon's application loading, it not pass, one check was passing and then again set to 0

After the status check was cleared, our application got deployed and within few minutes of deployment, the website was up and running.

The reason for the failure in the status check is unknown. I cannot find any information regarding the delay. Logs for the previous instance which got unhealthy is not available via S3.

I did not perform any manual steps to expedite the deployment process because until the windows instance does not pass the Status check nothing can be done. If I reset, again it will take the same time to initialize and perform a status check.

I did not perform any manual reset during the outage, I was collecting logs, keeping an eye on what is happening, checking if the instance was accessible via the internet. There was no action taken, and the issue got resolved automatically after the new instance loaded up and both status checks were completed.

Now, we don't know the cause of the issue. Attached are the screenshot of the issue. Questions:

1) Load Balancer does not have any feature to redirect the traffic to external or even alternate internal website during the outage (Link: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=72363). Are there ways to Automate redirect Load Balancer to a static page or any other host if the Amazon instance is down and is not healthy?

2) What to do in such situations where our instances are not running and how to quickly recover, With the current configuration, it takes 12-15 minutes to get the new instance and another 4-6 minute to get our application automatically deployed.

3) Why the status check fails, there was no spike in the network, traffic or CPU. Only Windows Instance was not reachable and Linux was reachable

4) Amazon terminates the non-healthy instance and adds a new one. I want to keep only 1 windows instance running during normal traffic/CPU usage. Is there any feature/method to get the logs before the instance is auto terminated by EC2 Scaling rules?

Image 1:

[image: Image-1]

Image 2:

[image: Image-2]

Image 3:

[image: Image-3]

Image 4:

[image: Image-4]

Image 5:

[image: Image-5]

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Load Balancer does not have any feature to redirect the traffic to external or even alternate internal website during the outage.(Link: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=72363) Are there ways to Automate redirect Load Balancer to a static page or any other host if the Amazon instance is down and is not healthy?
>
> 2) what to do in such situations where our instances are not running and how to quickly recover, With the current configuration, it takes 12-15 minutes to get the new instance and another 4-6 minute to get our application automatically deployed.

Run two instances all the time and setup DNS in route53 to point at one of them. The other is your "hot spare"

If an error condition occurs, alter route53 to switch servers.

See this blog article about how to achieve this using AWS Lambda https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-dynamic-dns-for-route-53-using-cloudwatch-events-and-lambda/